# How to compare different json show like git diff

Tags: python, django

I want check different 2 json result after i changed my code. This change maybe true or not, and i want show it like compare git diff.

My question is: How to compare text, and show different of this like git diff? Or anyway more friendly for user? I use python3 and django rest framework

Thank you very much

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Comment: Do you want to implement that thing in your Django project?

Comment: @Charnel if it can, yes. I maybe use button for generate new text, after that compare it with old version in django, and show it much friendly to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [diff-match-patch](https://pypi.org/project/diff-match-patch/)

It will show the changes with red (old) and green (new) text.